# parsing xml in perl program using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have so many various names

Input:

```
Depsai P.R.N.
D&#x00EA;nis De Castro
John D.J. 
Andrew E.
D.J. JOHN 
JOHN Mical D.J.
```

I need output like this.

```
D. P.R.N.
D. C.
J. D.J. 
A. E.
D.J. J.
J. M. D.J.
```

If the name like `D&#x00EA;nis De` Castro i need the output:  `D. C.` 
      If the name contains theses cases `(De|Di|Le|La|Van|Der)` in between should not capture the first word.

```
 use strict;
    use warnings;
    my $gn = qq(<name>Depsai P.R.N.</name>
                <name>D&#x00EA;nis De Castro</name>
                <name>Andrew E.</name>
                <name>John D.J.</name>
                <name>D.J. John</name>
                <name>John Mical D.J.</name>);
        my @int = $gn =~ m{<name>(.*?)</name>}ig;
        my $ini=();
        foreach my $initial(@int){
            $ini .= "$1\. " while($initial =~ s/(?:^|[ \.\,\;]+)([A-Z])\w*(\b|$)//s);
            $ini =~ s/ $//mi;
            print join("\n",$ini);exit;
        }

  Please give some regex pattern.
  Thanks advance.
```

Comment: removing the lowecase letters will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below one liner :

**InputFile:**

```
<name>Depsai P.R.N.</name>
<name>D&#x00EA;nis De Castro</name>
<name>John D.J.</name> 
<name>Andrew E.</name>
<name>D.J. JOHN</name> 
<name>JOHN Mical D.J.</name>
<name>Roc&#x00ED;o</name>
```

**On Windows cmd prompt:**

```
perl -lne "if($_ =~ /<name(>.*?<)\/name>/) {$result = $1; $result =~ s/(\s)(De|Di|Le|La|Van|Der)(\s)/$1$3/g; $result =~ s/((?:>|\s)[A-Z])[^\.]/$1\./g; $result =~ s/.*?(\s*[A-Z]\.\s*).*?/$1/g;$result =~ s/([a-z]|[A-Z][A-Z]).*?<//g;$result =~ s/<//g;print $result;}" InputFile
```

**On Unix:**

```
perl -lne 'if($_ =~ /<name(>.*?<)\/name>/) {$result = $1; $result =~ s/(\s)(De|Di|Le|La|Van|Der)(\s)/$1$3/g; $result =~ s/((?:>|\s)[A-Z])[^\.]/$1\./g; $result =~ s/.*?(\s*[A-Z]\.\s*).*?/$1/g;$result =~ s/([a-z]|[A-Z][A-Z]).*?<//g;$result =~ s/<//g;print $result;}' InputFile
```

**Output:**

```
D. P.R.N.
D. C.
J. D.J. 
A. E.
D.J. J.
J. M. D.J.
R.
```

Comment: You said do not capture first words if they are (De|Di|Le|La|Van|Der) in between then can you tell me what is the expected output of this D&#x00EA;nis Van Castro  and even for this D&#x00EA;nis John La Castro ?

Comment: For this case not working @Praveen <name>Roc&#x00ED;o</name> should come like <name>R.</name>

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+
```

You can try this.Replace by `.`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bB8jY7/12

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]')
test_str = u"Depsai P.R.N. \nJohn D.J. \nAndrew E."
subst = u"."

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: am not downvoted. now i edit the question. i need space if the initials have otherwise no need. i working in perl the lookbehind regex not working for me it shows error like not support for lookbehind. if space present in the name should come.

Comment: @depsai try now.See demo.

Comment: your code is working in regex101.com and regex buddy. but in perl program lookbehind regex not working please give some regex without using ?<=.

Comment: @depsai try `[a-z]+` replace by `.`.

Comment: thanks working i used this ([A-Z])([a-zA-Z]+) replace with $1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64215/discussion-between-depsai-and-vks).